# What part of App is considered Context? The java file, the .xml, or a part of one or the other?

Tags: android, android-context, android-bitmap

I've been trying to access images from my assets folder now instead of drawable in order to possibly alleviate some memory issues I'm having.

I found this code to aid with this:

```
public static Drawable getAssetImage(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
    AssetManager assets = context.getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open("drawable/" + filename + ".png")));
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer);
    return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
}
```

I'm confused what the context is though. Am I to pass it my MainActivity.java? Or reference it to a specific view? If anyone could explain this I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just pass your activity from which you are invoking this method.

Comment: getAssetImage(MainActivity, "pilots_cropped_edited.png");

Comment: so I'm in my MainActvitiy, but it says "expression expected" where I put in MainActivity. What part of the activity is it expecting. @Roman Samolyenko

Comment: use `MainActivity.this`. if it is in an activity. If it is a fragment. use `getContext()`